# how to run js file from Mongoshell

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My js file is having following code:

```
use testdb;   
var json = ["{\"Asset \":\"MiSeq\",\"Serial No\":\"4398\"}","{\"Asset \":\"MiSeq\",\"Serial No\":\"4398\"}"];

   setInterval(function(){ var values = json,
       valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
   db.testData.insert(valueToUse);
    }, 1000);
```

As i try to load this js file using my Mongo shell by:

```
load(d://insertJson.js);
```

I understand that it will be infinite loop, but i dont see any data inserted in mongodb

Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you execute setInterval in the MongoDb shell you get: `ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined`

Seems you can't use it in the mongodb shell.

maybe you can use a while loop, but i don't know how you could sleep for 1000ms. There is a sleep function in mongodb shell but i think that's not what you want: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/sleep/

Comment: [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) is a timer method provide by the standard Javascript `window` object that exists in web browsers / UIs.   The `mongo` shell does not include a `window` object; the closest equivalent would be a while loop with a `sleep()` as suggested.

Comment: The `sleep` database command forces the database to block all operations. That's not what you want. The `sleep()` javascript function in the mongo shell it is ok (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.0/src/mongo/scripting/utils.cpp#L55-L64)